# why $\frac{d}{dy}$ can pass through integral w.r.t. $x$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

When I calculate integration of multivariables, many books use the following step without proofing. I want to know that why it is true:
$$\frac{d}{dy}\left[\int^a_b f(x,y)dx\right]_{y=k}=\int^a_b \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left[f(x,y)\right]_{y=k}dx$$

I also wonder that whether it is true when the integral or differentiation become indefinite. Which is :
$$\frac{d}{dy}\int f(x,y)dx=\int\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y)dx$$
$$\frac{d}{dy}\int^a_b f(x,y)dx=\int^a_b \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y)dx$$
$$\frac{d}{dy}\left[\int f(x,y)dx\right]_{y=k}=\int \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left[f(x,y)\right]_{y=k}dx$$

Comment: This is an inverse version  of the formula $\partial^2 u/\partial x \partial y = \partial^2 u/\partial y \partial x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple terms, integration is a limiting case of summation (Riemann sums). Therefore, under [reasonable assumptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)  you can differentiate under the integral sign - just like the case with sums.

As for your other question, the general indefinite integral of $f(x,y)$ is $\int f(x,y)\mathrm{d} x=\int_{x_0}^xf(t,y) \mathrm{d}t+C$ where $x_0,C$ are constants. Applying the rule here gives the required result (again if the requirements of the theorem are met).

Comment: I don't really understand that why the limit can pass through the integral sign exactly. And what is meant by reasonable assumption? In which condition does this theorem not be applied?

Comment: If $f$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are continuous in a closed rectangle, they are uniformly continuous there. consider the  quotient $\frac{f(x,y+\Delta y)-f(x,y)}{\Delta y}$. Using the continuity hypothesis you can show that it tends to $\int f_y \mathrm d x$. The full proof can be found on the wiki page.

You can find a counterexample here http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/Notes/LeibnizRule.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a corollary of the dominated convergence theorem.